# Inserting into database works fine. Running tests on database connection refused

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker-compose

Running node.js with mocha, chai on docker with a postgres db. 
I use a yaml file to create all of my containers. I have a container for other things but in this case basically a container for my testing and a container for my database. I have a working insert function being called from my literate-app container. However, out of all the ways I tried I have not been able to connect to it from this new container used for testing that I am trying to test if a table exists in postgres

I have tried writing my own code. I have attempted to write the code several ways both using pg and pg-pool. The current code thats written that works and can insert doesn't work. I attempted to create a new user called test_user figuring maybe that was the case of it but to no avail.

Hers the error I get

```
Attaching to literate-webapp_test_1
test_1      |
test_1      | > @ mocha /literate-app
test_1      | > mocha --reporter spec ./test/test/postgressFactoryTest.js
test_1      |
test_1      |
test_1      |
test_1      |   PostGres
test_1      |     tableExists
test_1      |       1) should be 0 before connecting
test_1      | inside connect
test_1      |       2) should be not 0 after connecting
test_1      |     setName
test_1      |       ✓ should be "None Set" before calling"
test_1      |       ✓ should be "username" after calling
test_1      |     getCookie
test_1      |       3) should return a valid cookie string
test_1      |
test_1      |
test_1      |   2 passing (318ms)
test_1      |   3 failing
test_1      |
test_1      |   1) PostGres
test_1      |        tableExists
test_1      |          should be 0 before connecting:
test_1      |      AssertionError: expected 0 to equal undefined
test_1      |       at Context.<anonymous> (test/test/postgressFactoryTest.js:18:10)
test_1      |       at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:443:21)
test_1      |
test_1      |   2) PostGres
test_1      |        tableExists
test_1      |          should be not 0 after connecting:
test_1      |      TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
test_1      |       at Context.<anonymous> (test/test/postgressFactoryTest.js:38:7)
test_1      |       at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:443:21)
test_1      |
test_1      |   3) PostGres
test_1      |        getCookie
test_1      |          should return a valid cookie string:
test_1      |      ReferenceError: document is not defined
test_1      |       at PostGres.getCookie (literate-app/js/postgres.factory.js:273:43)
test_1      |       at Context.<anonymous> (test/test/postgressFactoryTest.js:90:25)
test_1      |       at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:443:21)
test_1      |
test_1      |
test_1      |
test_1      | (node:30) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postgres postgres:5432
test_1      |     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:58:26)
test_1      | (node:30) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
test_1      | (node:30) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will
terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
test_1      | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
test_1      | npm ERR! errno 3
test_1      | npm ERR! @ mocha: `mocha --reporter spec ./test/test/postgressFactoryTest.js`
test_1      | npm ERR! Exit status 3
test_1      | npm ERR!
test_1      | npm ERR! Failed at the @ mocha script.
test_1      | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
test_1      |
test_1      | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
test_1      | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-04-02T20_03_20_740Z-debug.log
```

Heres the docker yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  webapp:
    build: ./literate-app
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh","postgres:5432","--","npm","start"]
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    links:
      - postgres
    command: nodemon -e vue,js,css start.js
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=postgres
    ports:
     - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - literate-net


  server:
    build: ./readability-server
    command: nodemon -L --inspect=0.0.0.0:5555 server.js
    networks:
      - literate-net


  redis_db:
    image: redis:alpine
    networks:
      - literate-net


  postgres:
    restart: 'always'
    #image: 'bitnami/postgresql:latest'
    volumes:
     - /bitnami
     # - ./schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - literate-net
    environment:
      - "FILLA_DB_USER=my_user"
      - "FILLA_DB_PASSWORD=password123"
      - "FILLA_DB_DATABASE=my_database"
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password123"
    build: './database-creation'


  test: 
    image: node:latest
    build: ./test
    working_dir: /literate-app
    volumes:
      - .:/literate-app
    command:
      npm run mocha
    links:
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=postgres


networks:
  literate-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Heres the test file

```
describe('tableExists', function () {
    it('should be 0 before connecting', function () {

        var PostGres = new PostGresClass();
        var config = [];
        var value = PostGres.tableExists(config, 'alpharead');
        assert.equal(0, value);
    });

    it('should be not 0 after connecting', function () {

        var config = {
            user: 'my_user',
            host: 'postgres',
            database: 'my_database',
            password: 'password123',
            port: 5432,
            max: 20,
            idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
            connectionTimeoutMillis: 2000,
        };
        var pool = new Pool(config);

        pool.connect()
                console.log("inside connect")

                .then(client => {
                    console.log("querying client")
                    console.log("query return: " + client.query(`SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM pg_tables t WHERE tableowner=current_user and table_name= ${table_name} AND schema_name=my_database`))
                    return client.query(`SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM pg_tables t WHERE tableowner=current_user and table_name= ${table_name} AND schema_name=my_database`)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log("returning res")
                    console.log(res)
                    client.release()
                    return release()
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log("returning error")
                    console.log(err.stack)
                    return 0
                })
             })
        /*var PostGres = new PostGresClass();
        var config = {
            user: 'my_user',
            host: 'postgresql',
            database: 'my_database',
            password: 'password123',
            port: 5432,
            max: 20,
            idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
            connectionTimeoutMillis: 2000,
        };
        //var pool = new Pool(config);
        var value = PostGres.tableExists(config, `alpharead`);*/
        assert.equal(1, value);
    });
```

Heres the code that is actually connecting and inserting data

```
        logEvent(eventType, eventData, eSid, ePid){
            dt = new Date();
            var utcDate = dt.toUTCString();
            sid = eSid;
            pid = ePid;

            if(eventType == "Set Name/New Session"){
                this.setName(eventData)
            }
            pool.connect()
            .then(client => {
                return client.query('INSERT INTO public.alphatwo(sessionid, queryid, timestamp, eventtype, eventdata) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)', [sid, pid, utcDate, eventType, eventData])

                .then(res => {
                    console.log("successfully insterted data into alphatwo");
                        client.release();
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.log("didnt find database alphatwo or doesnt exist");
                    console.log(e);
                    client.release();
                })
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log("CAUGHT ERROR in connecting to database")
                console.log(e)
                client.release();
            })
        }
```

it has the same config set up just didnt wanna copy a lot of comments.

So the question is why can I not connecting to the database through this container. And what are some work arounds. Ive seen some docker files but this is exisiting and relies on the yaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer.

basically where it states

test: 
    image: node:latest
    build: ./test
    working_dir: /literate-app
    volumes:
      - .:/literate-app
    command:
      npm run mocha
    links:
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=postgres

the issue is this

```
links:
     -postgres
```

Docker now uses the network instead. So replacing that with

```
networks:
      - literate-net
```

resolved the issue